# Different Colors with FillStyle() and RoundRect()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So i wanted to have two filled rounded rectangle with a different color for each one but it give me the last color everytime

This is my code :

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

// #2e2e2e
// #00a6a4

ctx.fillStyle = "#00a6a4";
ctx.roundRect(10, 10, 100, 100,10);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "#2e2e2e";
ctx.roundRect(110, 110, 100, 100,10);
ctx.fill();
```

This is what it give me :

[script result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COePQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `ctx.beginPath()` after the first fill.

On the first fill you are filling one rect. But then on the second fill, you are filling **both** rectangles because you never start a new path, so you are just filling over that first rect.